# I can't load the AI model on web with Roboflow (solved)

Tags: javascript, artificial-intelligence, object-detection, roboflow

I’m trying to deploy my model on web. But it throws an error “I.map is not a function” when loading the model which is from a Roboflow tutorial. I tried to use the model i trained on Roboflow website and i get the same error. But there's some other model on Robolow is working perfectly with my code. I have no clue what's wrong with the model. Is there any way to fix it?

The model i use: https://universe.roboflow.com/roboflow-jvuqo/football-players-detection-3zvbc/dataset/1

```
const video = document.querySelector("#video"); 
let model; 
let cameraMode = "environment";  
const toLoad = {     
    model: "football-players-detection-3zvbc",         
    ersion: 4 
};                 
const loadModelPromise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {     
    roboflow.auth({         
        publishable_key: publishable_key     
    }).load(toLoad).then(function(m) {         
        model = m;         
        window.model = model;         
        resolve();     
    }); 
});
```

minimum code sample: https://codepen.io/meisken/pen/NWOXKZd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I upgraded Roboflow from 0.2.0 to 0.2.22. The bug is fixed.